# https + jquery issue

Tags: jquery, http, joomla, https

I have a responsive joomla template. My issue is my designer has  inserted jquery code  in index.php
"jQuery(".middle-col-full").insertAfter(".left-col");"

It works fine with http url but If I enable SSL then my page goes to infinite loop.

Anyone has idea.

Thanks

Comment: One idea is that you have added an infinity loop. Could you provide more information? This can't be solved if we don't have more information.

Comment: I need to ask you one thing so i can give you more clear reason.
If this div is already loaded in html. And then my designer has set this insertafter  syntax on domready. So, will it be reason?

and i don't understand that if its a infinite loop then why it woks with http(without ssl).

Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: My answer was a sarcastic one. You need to post your full code! Ofcourse could the `insertAfter` not create an infinity loop(only if `.middle-col-full` is infinity).

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with the code you've provided. It's most likely an PHP issue with a different code snippet. What version of Joomla are you using? Just out of curiosity, what happens if you temporarily remove that jQuery code snippet then load the website with https? Do you still get the loop?

Comment: Thank-you all for your help.
I just got the issue. It doesn't work with https because of ajax retrieving list.

Comment: Hey Lodder,
middle-col-full fetch the component body. and in component body I have a one state list which comes through ajax request... that was the issue.